# trying to put a JAX-RS resource class in a library doesn't work

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, glassfish, jax-rs

I've programmed a very simple chat JAX-RS application deployed with glassfish 4.1 in Netbeans with the following sources:

```
practica2/Message.java                   // entity from MySQL DataBase
practica2/service/AbstractFacade.java
                  ApplicationConfig.java
                  MessageFacadeREST.java // resource class
```

These source files are obtained executing Netbeans 'RESTful Web Services from Database' wizard against a MySQL database message with following attributes:

```
- id          INT(11)     flags: PK NN AI
- content     VARCHAR(250)       NN
- user_sender VARCHAR(45)        NN
- date        DATETIME           NN
```

The services in `MessageFacadeREST.java` consist of two methods: `create` and `retrieveFromDate`:

```
@POST
@Override
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public void create(Message entity) {
    super.create(entity);
}

@POST
@Path("from")
@Consumes({"application/xml","application/json"})
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public List<Message> retrieveFromDate(Message message) {
    // retrieves list of messages newer than message
}
```

Server works well and chat clients (mostly android) create and retrieve messages to/from the server.

Since my students have to complete `retrieveFromDate` I'd like to provide them with a binary `MessageFacadeREST.class` archive in a library. I prepare a `server2` folder with:

```
server2/practica2/service/MessageFacadeREST.class
```

adding this folder as a library and eliminating corresponding `.java` from sources. Then it stops working. What I've noticed is that Netbeans no longer adds `MessageFacadeREST.class` in `addRestResourceClasses()` method. If I try to load it manually:

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        //addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        resources.add(practica2.service.MessageFacadeREST.class);
        return resources;
    }

    /**
     * Do not modify addRestResourceClasses() method.
     * It is automatically populated with
     * all resources defined in the project.
     * If required, comment out calling this method in getClasses().
     */
    //private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
    //}
}
```

I get:

```
GlassFish Server (1), deploy, null, false
/home/francesc/NetBeansProjects/WebApplication1/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1049: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Then the question is: how can I split a working JAX-RS application between sources and binary class libraries?

---

(SOLVED):
First of all, thanks to @John Ament and @OndrejM for their valuable comments. In my original post I had almost found the solution. Two points to take into account:

1.- When distributing resources as .class make sure to register to JAX-RS runtime: manual loading of `MessageFacadeREST.class` is mandatory.

2.- In Netbeans it seems that run option doesn't redeploy correctly ('The module has not been deployed' error). deploy option (instead of run) must be used

Now it works.

Comment: Are you packaging your application in a WAR file?

Comment: yes. This is the other alternative. Deploying WAR works well, but I'd prefer to execute a mixed binary(class)/source hybrid application

Comment: @John Ament just a clarification. If I deploy war from the 3 sources, it works well, but if I deploy from 2 sources and one class file, it fails

Comment: TBH, I'm not sure what that means.  If you've built the library, they will need that library as a resource.  You would need to include a reference to that pre-built library.

Comment: @John All this is done automatically. I add library as a folder with only one class file, and when project is built class file appears correctly in war file: `WEB-INF/classes/practica2/service/MessageFacadeREST.class`. Deploying war only works when war file has been built from the three sources but not when it has been built from two sources and the class file. It's strange

Comment: Please do not use "SOLVED" in your title and post the solution you found as a proper answer. You can then even accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans probably deletes the `.class` files after you removed the sources from the project.

You have to copy the `.class` files into a folder where Netbeans searches for resource files.

In classical Netbeans Java Web project, that would be in `WEB-INF` folder, by default `web/WEB-INF`. You can also copy the classes to any other folder and add the folder as a Library, in Compile tab (In project properties dialog).

If the project is maven-based project, just copy the folder with classes into the `src/main/resources` folder.